# discord.py - send embed in custom exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How can I send an embed on a custom exception?

Exception:

```py
class CustomError(commands.CommandError):
    
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message
```

Code where the exception gets called:

```py
if not ctx.voice_client or ctx.voice_client.queue.is_empty():
    raise CustomError(
        message="Your queue seems to be empty."
    )

return True
```

I want the bot to send an embed with the **message** as description in the chat.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid solution but a ugly one. I would suggest having a helper method to create and send embed and using that to send message whenever you raise an Exception.

```py
class CustomError(commands.CommandError):
    
    def __init__(self, message, ctx):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)
        # create embed; customize as you like
        em = discord.Embed(title="Error in command", description=message)
        # non-async function cannot use aync functions so use create_task
        ctx.bot.loop.create_task(ctx.send(embed=em))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message


# Then inside a command, where ctx is context ie first argument to command(excluding self where relevant)
# It is not valid in event handlers
raise CustomError("Hello there", ctx)
```

For event handlers, `ctx.bot` should be replaced by an instance of `discord.Client` or `discord.Bot` depending on how you are initializing your bot. `ctx.send` should be replaced by `channel.send` where channel is the TextChannel object where you want to send the embed. You can add both as arguments to __init__.

Example of a helper method. There are multiple methods of doing this.

```py
# Title is optional
async def send_embed(channel, message, title=''):
    em = discord.Embed(title=title, description=message)
    await channel.send(embed=em)
```

Example usage:
`await send_embed(ctx, "You have an error")`

Comment: and using `.loop.create_task()` is the only way to send something in an exception?

Comment: @Alado It is the cleanest method I know that can call async function from sync function. There are others such as run_in_executor but it requires creating an executor. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). There may be others that I do not know of but that would be a new question.

Comment: There are probably existing question on how to run async function inside sync functions.

Comment: To clarify create_task is not used because it is an exception. It is used because the message is sent from __init__ method and sending a message(`ctx.send`) is a async function. Normally you would define method(command handlers are async) as async and use `await ctx.send()`. However, you cannot make init async.  Hence, the workaround.

Comment: Yeah I know. Your option worked, thank you :) Is there any way, that I do not also see the error in the cmd line?

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted. The whole point of exceptions is that you get a traceback of when and where the error occurred. To notify the user, use a helper method to send the embed instead of Exception.

Comment: I thinks thats more what I really wanna do, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Alado Edited. This comment section is getting long. Its really not intended to chat here.